# Why isn't the score showing up after segue on different view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

Iv created a quiz app, that tracks the user's score till the user gets to the end. There is an if statement - when it reaches the end of the quiz, a results View controller pops up. My Question is I want to get the same score value presented at the end on the resultsViewContoller. I have connected it via segue and the identifier has been placed. **The app runs but when i get to the end the segue opens up the page but the score doesnt change?**

How can i solve this problem?

The user finishes the app. I call the segue method and the screen comes up.

Results View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var fruitness = Fruitness()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var finalScoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    var finalScore: String!
    
    override func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            
            finalScoreLabel.text = finalScore
            
            
            if finalScore != nil {
                finalScoreLabel.text = "FINALSCORE:\(String(describing: Int(finalScore!)))"
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Game View Controller

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var fruitLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var replayGame: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton0: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton5: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton6: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton7: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton8: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet private var fruitButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    var score = 0
    var fruitness = Fruitness()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        updateUI()
        
    }
    @IBAction func replayGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
        fruitness.restartGame() //Calling restart
        updateUI()
        
        
    }
    @IBAction func touchButton(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        
        //The userGotItRight is = to the checkAnswer function which goes through the fruitOptions array to make sure the answer is corrct. T/F
        let userGotItRight = checkAnswer(userAnswer: userAnswer)
        
        if userGotItRight {
            //Depending if the user got the answer correct the button turns green/red
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        
        nextFruit() //Calling the next Fruit untill all the fruit items have been displayed.
        
        //This timer is responsible for the UIColors green, red and clear. Without this timer the color drags onto the next fruit.
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo:nil, repeats: false)
        
    }
    
    //    This check answer method needs an input to work. The input is the answer the user-choose (String).
    func checkAnswer(userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
        
        //        Checks if the user got the answer correct. T/F
        if userAnswer == fruitness.fruitOptions[fruitness.fruitNumber].fruit {
            fruitness.score += 1 //We increase the value of score when we get the answer right.
            //   fruitness.finalScorez = fruitness.score
            
            return true
        } else {
            return false
            
        }
    }
    //Checks to make sure the eveytime it hits 0 it will shuffle.
    func nextFruit() {
        if fruitness.fruitNumber == 0 {
            fruitness.fruitOptions.shuffle()
            
        }
        // print(fruitness.fruitOptions[fruitness.fruitNumber]) //Only gets printed in the consol
        
        if fruitness.fruitNumber + 1 < fruitness.fruitOptions.count {
            fruitness.fruitNumber += 1
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResultsVC", sender: self) //To call Segue
        }
    }
    
    //Connecting and controlling oF the Segue and from GameView COntroller -> Results view controller.
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResultsVC" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
            destinationVC.finalScore = scoreLabel.text //Printing the final score at the end.
        }
     
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        
        //Controlls the background. Clearing ability between T/F answers.
        optionButton0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton4.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton5.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton6.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton7.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton8.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        //The fruit name available that the user needs to match.
        fruitLabel.text = fruitness.getFruitText()
        
        //Displaying the progress of the user till they reach the end.
        progressBar.progress = fruitness.getProgress()
        
        //Displaying the score at all times
        scoreLabel.text = "SCORE: \(fruitness.score)"
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code.

First off, the `prepare(for:sender:)` method gets called on the source view controller that triggers the segue, not the destination view controller.

Second, your `ResultsViewController` has a `viewWillAppear(_:)` method nested inside its `prepare(for:sender:)` method. Don't do that. The `viewWillAppear(_:)` method needs to be a top-level method of your view controller or it won't get called.

Also, `viewWillAppear(_:)` methods should call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`.

Your ResultsViewController's viewWillAppear method should look like this:

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    finalScoreLabel.text = finalScore
}
```

The `prepare(for:sender:)` method in your `GameViewController` should set `finalScore` in your `ResultsViewController` so that when its `viewWillAppear` is called, `finalScore` has a value.

### Edit:

(It looks like you got that last part correct. Your GameViewController's `prepare(for:sender)` does appear to set `finalScore`. Note, however, that you are using `scoreLabel` to hold your `finalScoreValue`. You should not save state in view objects. You should have a var in `GameViewController` that holds your score. You could make `GameViewController` set your `score` var, and have a `didSet()` method on the score var that installs the updated score value into the scoreLabel.)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToResultsVC" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
        destinationVC.finalScore = scoreLabel.text //Printing the final score at the end.
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you..iv been stuck for hours mate!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wish to refactor your repetitive code to this one:

```
let optionButtonArray = [optionButton0,optionButton1 ...]
optionButtonArray.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear }
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but this isn't an answer to the OPs question.